# "mkdir || echo && exit" exiting even when mkdir succeeds

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

> mkdir $2 ||  echo "I can't create directory $2" && exit 8

Hi everyone, this is my first post here, so be kind.

I am making a script right now and this line troubles me.

The exit 8 should happen only if the directory $2 cannot be created. 
After running the script and successfully creating that directory, it still exits on 8.

Am I missing something? I thought the command after " || " happens only if you get a false on the left side.

I am new to the Linux world, and as a guy with a little to medium C experience I am confused, help! (using ubuntu, bash, btw)

Comment: I think it is because of the precedence of operators. You can put parentheses. If mkdir fails, you execute echo and it returns true, so the third command is executed. Maybe you could use parenthesis

Comment: He's an answer from the Unix&Linux SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/precedence-of-the-shell-logical-operators

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @fernand0 suggested, the problem is the precedence of the `||` and `&&` operators. You want it to run something like `mkdir || ( echo && exit )` -- that is, run the `echo && exit` part if `mkdir` fails. But what it's actually doing is running something like `( mkdir || echo ) && exit` -- that is, it runs the `exit` part if either the `mkdir` OR `echo` command succeeds. `echo` will almost always succeed, so it'll almost always exit.

So, you need to explicitly group the commands, to override this precedence. But don't use `( )`, because that runs its contents in a subshell, and `exit` will just exit the subshell, not the main script; you can use `{ }` instead, or use an explicit `if` block. Also, you don't actually want `echo && exit`, because that runs `exit` only if the `echo` command succeeds. `echo` almost always succeeds, but in the rare case that it fails I'm pretty sure you want the script to exit anyway.

When I need to do something like this in a script, I usually use this idiom:

```
mkdir "$2" || {
    echo "I can't create directory $2" >&2
    exit 8
}
```

(Note: as @CharlesDuffy suggested, I added double-quotes around `$2` -- double-quoting variable references is almost always a good idea in case they contain any spaces, wildcards, etc. I also sent the error message to standard error (`>&2`) instead of standard output, which is also generally a better way to do things.)

If you want to be terser, you can put it all on one line:

```
mkdir "$2" || { echo "I can't create directory $2" >&2; exit 8; }
```

Note that the final `;` (or a line break) is required before the `}`, or the shell thinks `}` is just an argument to `exit`. You could also go the other way and use an explicit `if` block:

```
if ! mkdir "$2"; then
    echo "I can't create directory $2" >&2
    exit 8
fi
```

This option is less clever and concise, but that's a good thing -- clever and concise is exactly what caused this problem in the first place; clear and unambiguous is much better for code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Done!

Comment: Do you know how much I love you? Also, could you help me out with this: > var=$(file -b $1 | grep "ISO") 
 I have that line in a script. if file fails (eg: when there is no argument), I get a huge error message about its usage. How to send that error message to /dev/null, using the 2> ? I tried a few options, none of them worked.

Comment: @NuSuntStudent You need to redirect the stderr of the command printing the error, so `var=$(file -b "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep "ISO")`. Note that I also added double-quotes around `$1`, which will change the error message to one about not finding a file with no name. I'd recommend adding sanity-checks on the script's arguments at the beginning of the script (e.g. `if [ -z "$1" ]; then echo "Usage: ..." >&2; exit 1; fi`). This allows you to give a descriptive error, rather than the user having to figure out what's wrong from what parts of the script failed.

Comment: "clever and concise is exactly what caused this problem in the first place". Well said.

Answer (score 1):

`||` and `&&` do not have the precedence you are accustomed to in other languages. Unparenthesized, it is equivalent to `(a || b) && c` (strictly left-to-right), not `a || (b && c)` (where `&&` has higher precedence than `||`). It's rarely a good idea to chain commands together with a mix of `||` and `&&`; instead, use an `if` statement.

```
if ! mkdir "$2"; then
  echo "I can't create directory $2" >&2
  exit 8
fi
```

If you really want to use the list operators, use `{ ... }` to group commands appropriately.

```
mkdir "$2" || { echo "I can't create directory $2" >&2; exit 8; }
```

Comment: `echo && exit` is bad form -- do we really want to avoid exiting if `echo` fails? That should be `mkdir "$2" || { echo "..." >&2; exit 8; }`

Comment: Agreed, although if an `echo` that simple fails, you probably have bigger problems to fix.